# Npm start error. React

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to do

> npm start

In my react project but always have a problem

```
npm ERR! path /Users/dan/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/dan/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dan/.npm/_logs/2018-04-11T17_50_33_041Z-debug.log
```

I've also know that 5 version of npm isn't the best. Because I've reinstall npm and now I've:

> node -v

v8.11.1

> npm -v

4.6.1

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use `create-react-app` CLI ?

Comment: @Ali Bahaari, of course.

Comment: Have you installed it with `-g` option ?

Comment: Try **npm install npm@latest -g** as @Ali bahaari said

Comment: @Ali Bahaari, I don't know how but when I've done `create-react-app` for the tenth time it's working now... But Do you recommend to use `create-react-app -g` instead `create-react-app`?

Comment: @dhruv soni, In my case works just npm version 4...

Comment: @helsereet Yes, Maybe it doesn't have access globally. Try it.

Comment: Are you sure you were in the folder which have the package.json? Because the error is the same when I forget to make `cd` in my project ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrade react-script

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 --save
```

It's work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands:

```sh
npx create-react-app myfirstreact
cd myfirstreact
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work unless there are no files to work within the project.

Check if your react boilerplate template was fully generated by `create-react-app` otherwise you will need to **upgrade** your `create-react-app`

One way to know the template is not generated is if the `src` folder in your project directory does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is you are not in main file please run this command
cd-your file name